# Are there any opitions to soldering on a pinheader if you only want to use it once?

Tags: soldering

I have bought sonoff, it's a really nice electric switch with wifi. I want to flash it with a new firmware, using an FTDI adapter. In the tutorials I have found, they recommend that you solder on a pinheader onto the circuitboard (there are 5 small holes where it would fit).

I don't have the equipment and I really suck at soldering, so I wonder if there is any other options for connectig the FTDI to the board, I only need to do it once per sonoff, ever.

This is what it's suppose to look like, my sonoff is another version, so it's a lot trickier positioned.[image]

Here is the sonoff if that matters
https://www.itead.cc/smart-home/sonoff-wifi-wireless-switch.html

Comment: I use a row of extra long pin headers to flash my sonoffs the first time. i used to use a knead-able eraser jig but it stopped fitting new ones so now i just hold it...

Comment: Looks like a wood clothespin is about the right size to hold 4 pins on the pads while you flash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Especially with a single-row header into plated-through holes (the norm on a commercially made double sided board), if the programming process doesn't take too long **and if you know that any failure is recoverable** then you can usually get away with just holding some sideways finger presser on the *unsoldered* header.

Don't try to *leave* it like that; it will only work with pressure applied to maintain contact.

Production setups usually use sprung contact pins ("pogo pins") in a clamping jig.  There are also manual temporary fixtures that have a grid of sprung contacts and alignment pins, but the board typically needs to be specially designed with the unique footprint of the pin array.